# Getting error while installing DotNetNuke?

Tags: connection, dotnetnuke

Error:

The following error has occurred during the installation of application: Installation of DotNetNuke at https://mccallumtech.com/dnn/ failed. Non-zero exit status returned by script. Output stream: 'Error during MSSQL version checking

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error.

at (SiteApplicationManager::fsaExecuteScript line 468)
at execute console command --run-application-script(vconsoleapp::start line 93)
at execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\admin\bin\sappmng" --run-application-script "--script-filename=configure" "--fsa-xml-file=C:/Program Files (x86)/Plesk/PrivateTemp/afrE9E7.tmp" "--script-name=install" "--user-name=mccallum" "--application-full-name=file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\var\apspackages\adi431B.tmp.zip4931ec96-b5f6-4785-d5\cache"(vconsoleapp::run line 110)
(Error code 1)'. Error stream: 'Error during MSSQL version checking

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error.

at (SiteApplicationManager::fsaExecuteScript line 468)
at execute console command --run-application-script(vconsoleapp::start line 93)
at execute "C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\admin\bin\sappmng" --run-application-script "--script-filename=configure" "--fsa-xml-file=C:/Program Files (x86)/Plesk/PrivateTemp/afrE9E7.tmp" "--script-name=install" "--user-name=mccallum" "--application-full-name=file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\var\apspackages\adi431B.tmp.zip4931ec96-b5f6-4785-d5\cache"(vconsoleapp::run line 110)
(Error code 1)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that error message it appears to be occurring BEFORE the DNN installation process as the commands that you are seeing in error are not part of the DNN Installation.

DNN Installation is always triggered either by Install.aspx (silent install) or InstallWizard.aspx (Guided install)

It appears you might be using a Plesk packaged installation, I would check with your hosting provider.